# "Error: could not find driver" triggers "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null"

Tags: pdo, centos, opencart, centos7, php-7.0

Basically when I try to load a page, the exact error message reads:

```
Error: could not find driver
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /var/www/vhosts/FileA.php:46 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/FileB.php(120): Database4->numofrows('select a.cardco...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/FileA.php:46 on `line 46`
```

So I went to the offending FileA.php file and went to line 46 as they said above.

FileA.php

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time',3600);
    Class Database4{
        protected $username;
        protected $password;
        protected $server;
        protected $dbName;
        public $conn;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->connection();
        }
        public function __destruct(){
            $this->conn=null;
        }
        protected function connection(){
            try{
                $this->username='dummyUser';
                $this->password='dummyPass';
                $this->server='192.168.0.42';
                $this->dbName='dummyDatabase';
                $this->conn=new PDO('dblib:host='.$this->server.':1433;dbname='.$this->dbName, $this->username, $this->password);

           } catch (PDOException $e){echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
       }
    }

            public function insert($sqlInsert)
    {
        $stmt=$this->conn->prepare($sqlInsert);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function update($sqlUpdate){
        $stmt=$this->conn->prepare($sqlUpdate);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }
    public function delete($sqlDelete){
        $stmt=$this->conn->prepare($sqlDelete);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }
    public function select($sqlSelect){ 
        $stmt=$this->conn->prepare($sqlSelect);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }
    public function numofrows($sql){
        $stmt=$this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $numofrows= count($stmt->fetchAll());
        return $numofrows;
    }
}
?>
```

After looking at the code, it seems that there is an overwhelming amount of answers saying that perhaps the problem is located on `line 22` of `FileA.php` and I would need to check if I have pdo_mysql installed.

To check, I went and took a look at
/etc/php.ini here's what I managed to find inside of it.

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll;
extension=php_pdo.dll;
extension=pdo.so;
extension=pdo_mysql.so;
```

Feeling stumped, I went to take a look at FileB.php feeling lost at this point.

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time',3600);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    include ("/FileA.php");
    include ("/irrelevant.php");
    $db4=New Database4;
    $db7=New Database7;

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Creator")
                                ->setLastModifiedBy("Creator")
                                ->setTitle("Title")
                                ->setSubject("Subject")
                                ->setDescription("Description")
                                ->setKeywords("keywords")
                                ->setCategory("category");

    $cart_size=array(
    "2kg"=>array(
        "length"=>250,
        "width"=>200,
        "height"=>155,
        "weight"=>2    
    ),
    "5kg"=>array(
        "length"=>300,
        "width"=>200,
        "height"=>300,
        "weight"=>5
    ),
    "8kg"=>array(
        "length"=>400,
        "width"=>300,
        "height"=>250,
        "weight"=>8
    ),
    "15kg"=>array(
        "length"=>500,
        "width"=>400,
        "height"=>300,
        "weight"=>15
    ),
    "25kg"=>array(
        "length"=>500,
        "width"=>500,
        "height"=>400,
        "weight"=>25
    )

    );                       
    $csv_array=array();
    $csv_array[]="C_CONSIGNMENT_ID,C_POST_CHARGE_TO_ACCOUNT,C_CHARGE_CODE,C_MERCHANT_CONSIGNEE_CODE,C_CONSIGNEE_NAME,C_CONSIGNEE_BUSINESS_NAME,C_CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS_1,C_CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS_2,C_CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS_3,C_CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS_4,C_CONSIGNEE_SUBURB,C_CONSIGNEE_STATE_CODE,C_CONSIGNEE_POSTCODE,C_CONSIGNEE_COUNTRY_CODE,C_CONSIGNEE_PHONE_NUMBER,C_PHONE_PRINT_REQUIRED,C_CONSIGNEE_FAX_NUMBER,C_DELIVERY_INSTRUCTION,C_SIGNATURE_REQUIRED,C_PART_DELIVERY,C_COMMENTS,C_ADD_TO_ADDRESS_BOOK,C_CTC_AMOUNT,C_REF,C_REF_PRINT_REQUIRED,C_REF2,C_REF2_PRINT_REQUIRED,C_CHARGEBACK_ACCOUNT,C_RECURRING_CONSIGNMENT,C_RETURN_NAME,C_RETURN_ADDRESS_1,C_RETURN_ADDRESS_2,C_RETURN_ADDRESS_3,C_RETURN_ADDRESS_4,C_RETURN_SUBURB,C_RETURN_STATE_CODE,C_RETURN_POSTCODE,C_RETURN_COUNTRY_CODE,C_REDIR_COMPANY_NAME,C_REDIR_NAME,C_REDIR_ADDRESS_1,C_REDIR_ADDRESS_2,C_REDIR_ADDRESS_3,C_REDIR_ADDRESS_4,C_REDIR_SUBURB,C_REDIR_STATE_CODE,C_REDIR_POSTCODE,C_REDIR_COUNTRY_CODE,C_MANIFEST_ID,C_CONSIGNEE_EMAIL,C_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION,C_APCN,C_SURVEY,C_DELIVERY_SUBSCRIPTION,C_EMBARGO_DATE,C_SPECIFIED_DATE,C_DELIVER_DAY,C_DO_NOT_DELIVER_DAY,C_DELIVERY_WINDOW,C_CDP_LOCATION,C_IMPORTERREFNBR,C_SENDER_NAME,C_SENDER_CUSTOMS_REFERENCE,C_SENDER_BUSINESS_NAME,C_SENDER_ADDRESS_LINE1,C_SENDER_ADDRESS_LINE2,C_SENDER_ADDRESS_LINE3,C_SENDER_SUBURB_CITY,C_SENDER_STATE_CODE,C_SENDER_POSTCODE,C_SENDER_COUNTRY_CODE,C_SENDER_PHONE_NUMBER,C_SENDER_EMAIL,C_RTN_LABEL,A_ACTUAL_CUBIC_WEIGHT,A_LENGTH,A_WIDTH,A_HEIGHT,A_NUMBER_IDENTICAL_ARTS,A_CONSIGNMENT_ARTICLE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,A_IS_DANGEROUS_GOODS,A_IS_TRANSIT_COVER_REQUIRED,A_TRANSIT_COVER_AMOUNT,A_CUSTOMS_DECLARED_VALUE,A_CLASSIFICATION_EXPLANATION,A_EXPORT_CLEARANCE_NUMBER,A_IS_RETURN_SURFACE,A_IS_RETURN_AIR,A_IS_ABANDON,A_IS_REDIRECT_SURFACE,A_IS_REDIRECT_AIR,A_PROD_CLASSIFICATION,A_IS_COMMERCIAL_VALUE,G_ORIGIN_COUNTRY_CODE,G_HS_TARIFF,G_DESCRIPTION,G_PRODUCT_TYPE,G_PRODUCT_CLASSIFICATION,G_QUANTITY,G_WEIGHT,G_UNIT_VALUE,G_TOTAL_VALUE";
    $line1=$csv_array[0];
    $csv_array[]="IGNORED,OPTIONAL,MANDATORY,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,OPTIONAL,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,IGNORED,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,MANDATORY,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,OPTIONAL,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY,OPTIONAL,OPTIONAL,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE,MANDATORY/OPTIONAL REFER TO GUIDE";
    $line2=$csv_array[1];
    $xlsx="Online_Order_".date("Ymd").".xlsx";
    $xlsxPath=__DIR__."/online-order"."/$xlsx";
    $line1Array=array();
    $line1Array=explode(",",$line1);
    $line2Array=array();
    $line2Array=explode(",",$line2);
    $line3Array=array();
    $titleCounter=0;
    $letter='A';
    foreach ($line1Array as $line){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter."1",$line);

        $letter++;
        $titleCounter++;
    }
    $letter='A';
    foreach ($line2Array as $line){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter."2",$line);        
        $letter++;
    }

    $letter='A';
    for ($i=0;$i<$titleCounter;$i++){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($letter)->setAutoSize(true);
    $letter++;
    }

    $sqlGetSalesOrderHeader="select a.cardcode as cardcode, a.cardname as cardname, a.numatcard as numatcard, a.docnum as docnum, a.docdate as docdate,  c.CountyS as customer, c.StreetS as company, c.CityS as suburb, c.ZipCodeS as postcode, c.StateS as state, c.CountryS as country, a.U_UDF_Freight, CAST(a.U_UDF_IntCom AS TEXT) as U_UDF_IntCom, a.U_WC1_PHNE as U_WC1_PHNE, a.U_WC1_EMIL as U_WC1_EMIL, c.BlockS as address  
    from ordr a, rdr12 c
    where (a.cardcode='c00001' or a.cardcode='c00002') and  a.docentry=c.docentry and a.docstatus='o' and a.printed='Y'
    order by a.docdate asc";

    function outputCSV($csv_array, $full_path){
        $outputBuffer=fopen($full_path,"w");
        foreach($csv_array as $val){
            $line=explode(",",$val);
            fputcsv($outputBuffer,$line);
        }
        fclose($outputBuffer);
    }
    $total_order=$db4->numofrows($sqlGetSalesOrderHeader);
    if ($db4->numofrows($sqlGetSalesOrderHeader)>0){
        $resultGetSalesOrderHeader=$db4->select($sqlGetSalesOrderHeader);
        $rowsGetSalesOrderHeaders=$resultGetSalesOrderHeader->fetchAll();
        foreach ($rowsGetSalesOrderHeaders as $rowsGetSalesOrderHeader){
            $cardcode=$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['cardcode'];
            $cardname=$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['cardname'];
            $numatcard=$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['numatcard'];
            $docnum=$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['docnum'];
            $docdate=$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['docdate'];
            $customer=str_replace(","," ",$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['customer']);
            $address=str_replace(","," ",$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['address']);
            $suburb=$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['suburb'];
            $state=$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['state'];
            $postcode=$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['postcode'];
            $country=$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['country'];
            $phone=$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['U_WC1_PHNE'];
            $company=str_replace("=","",$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['company']);
            $freight_instruction=str_replace(",", " ",$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['U_UDF_Freight']);
            if (empty($freight_instruction)){
                $freight_instruction="Deliver during business hours.";
            }
            else{
                $freight_instruction="Deliver during business hours. ".$freight_instruction;
            }
            $cust_type=(stripos($rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['U_UDF_IntCom'],'business')!==false?"Business":"Residential");
            $email=$rowsGetSalesOrderHeader['U_WC1_EMIL'];
            if ($email==""){
                $notify="NONE";
            }else{
                $notify="DISPATCH";
            }
            $weight=0;
            $length=0;
            $width=0;
            $height=0;
            $tempLength=0;
            $tempHeight=0;
            $tempWidth=0;
            $sqlGetOrder="
        select d.itemcode as itemcode, d.quantity as quantity    
        from ordr a, rdr12 c, rdr1 d, oitm e
        where (a.cardcode='c00001' or a.cardcode='c00002')  and  a.docentry=c.docentry and a.docentry=d.docentry and a.docstatus='o' and e.itemcode=d.itemcode and a.numatcard='$numatcard' and a.printed='Y'
        ";
            $resultGetOrder=$db4->select($sqlGetOrder);
            while ($rowsGetOrder=$resultGetOrder->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
                $sItemcode=$rowsGetOrder['itemcode'];
                $sQuantity=$rowsGetOrder['quantity'];
                $sqlGetProducts="select weight, length, width, height from las_product_dimension where itemcode='$sItemcode'";
                $resultGetProducts=$db7->select($sqlGetProducts);
                while ($rowsGetProducts=mysqli_fetch_array($resultGetProducts)){
                    $dWeight=$rowsGetProducts[0];
                    $dLength=$rowsGetProducts[1];
                    $dWidth=$rowsGetProducts[2];
                    $dHeight=$rowsGetProducts[3];

                    if ($tempLength>$dLength){
                    $length=$tempLength;
                    }else{
                    $length=$dLength;
                    }
                    if ($tempWidth>$dWidth){
                        $width=$tempWidth;
                    }else{
                        $width=$dWidth;
                    }
                    $height+=$dHeight * $sQuantity;
                    $weight+=$dWeight * $sQuantity;
                    $tempWidth=$dWidth;
                    $tempLength=$dLength;   
                }
            }
            $csv_array[]=",,7D55,,$customer,$company,$address,,,,$suburb,$state,$postcode,$country,$phone,N,,$freight_instruction,Y,N,,Y,,$docnum,N,,N,,N,Laser Corporation Holdings Pty Ltd,Unit 1/6-8 Byfield St,,,,MACQUARIE PARK,NSW,2113,AU,,,,,,,,,,,,$email,$notify,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,N,$weight,$length,$width,$height,,,N,N,0,0,,,,,,,,,";
            $line3Array[]=",,7D55,,$customer,$company,$address,,,,$suburb,$state,$postcode,$country,$phone,N,,$freight_instruction,Y,N,,Y,,$docnum,N,,N,,N,Laser Corporation Holdings Pty Ltd,Unit 1/6-8 Byfield St,,,,MACQUARIE PARK,NSW,2113,AU,,,,,,,,,,,,$email,$notify,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,N,$weight,$length,$width,$height,,,N,N,0,0,,,,,,,,,";
        }
            $filename="exported_online_order_".date('Ymd').".csv";
            $full_path=__DIR__."/online-order/".$filename;
            outputCSV($csv_array, $full_path);
            $cust_array=array();
            $lineCount=3;
            foreach($line3Array as $line){
                $cust_array=explode(",",$line);
                $letter='A';

                foreach($cust_array as $cust_line){
                    if ($letter=='O'){
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit($letter.$lineCount,$cust_line,PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
                    }
                    else{
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter.$lineCount,$cust_line);
                    }
                $letter++;
                }
                $lineCount++;
            }

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Online Order');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setVisible(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setVisible(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setVisible(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setVisible(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setVisible(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('Q')->setVisible(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('U')->setVisible(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('W')->setVisible(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('Z')->setVisible(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AB')->setVisible(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AF')->setVisible(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AG')->setVisible(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AH')->setVisible(false);

            for ($col='AM'; $col!='BX'; $col++){
                if ($col!='AX' && $col!="AY" && $col!="BW" ){
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($col)->setVisible(false);
                }
            }
            for ($col='CA'; $col!='CY'; $col++){
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($col)->setVisible(false);
            }

        $objPHPExcel->createSheet(NULL, 1);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Order");  
        $letter='A';
        $lineCount=1;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','Document Number');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1','Order ID');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1','Product');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1','Quantity');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1','Customer Code');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1','Company Name');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G1','Customer Name');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H1','Address');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I1','Suburb');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J1','State');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K1','Postcode');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L1','Country');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M1','Freight Instruction');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('N1','Customer Type');
        $lineCount=2;

        $sqlGetItem="
        select a.cardcode as cardcode, a.cardname as cardname, d.itemcode as itemcode, d.quantity as quantity, a.numatcard as numatcard, a.docnum as docnum, a.docdate as docdate,  c.CountyS as customer, c.BlockS as address, c.CityS as suburb, c.ZipCodeS as postcode, c.StateS as state, c.CountryS as country, a.U_UDF_Freight, CAST(a.U_UDF_IntCom AS TEXT) as U_UDF_IntCom 
        from ordr a, rdr12 c, rdr1 d
        where (a.cardcode='c00001' or a.cardcode='c00002') and  a.docentry=c.docentry and a.docentry=d.docentry and a.docstatus='o' and a.printed='Y'
        order by a.docdate asc
        ";

        $resultGetItem=$db4->select($sqlGetItem);
        while ($rowsGetItem=$resultGetItem->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
            $cardcode=$rowsGetItem['cardcode'];
            $cardname=$rowsGetItem['cardname'];
            $numatcard=$rowsGetItem['numatcard'];
            $docnum=$rowsGetItem['docnum'];
            $docdate=$rowsGetItem['docdate'];
            $customer=str_replace(","," ",$rowsGetItem['customer']);
            $customer=str_replace("=","",$customer);
            $address=str_replace(","," ",$rowsGetItem['address']);
            $suburb=$rowsGetItem['suburb'];
            $state=$rowsGetItem['state'];
            $postcode=$rowsGetItem['postcode'];
            $country=$rowsGetItem['country'];
            $itemcode=$rowsGetItem['itemcode'];
            $quantity=$rowsGetItem['quantity'];
            $freight_instruction=str_replace(",", " ",$rowsGetItem['U_UDF_Freight']);
            $cust_type=(stripos($rowsGetItem['U_UDF_IntCom'],'business')!==false?"Business":"Residential");

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A$lineCount", $docnum);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("B$lineCount", $numatcard);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("C$lineCount", $itemcode);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("D$lineCount", $quantity);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("E$lineCount", $cardcode);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("F$lineCount", $cardname);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("G$lineCount", $customer);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("H$lineCount", $address);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("I$lineCount", $suburb);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("J$lineCount", $state);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("K$lineCount", $postcode);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("L$lineCount", $country);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("M$lineCount", $freight_instruction);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("N$lineCount", $cust_type);
            $lineCount++;
        }
            for ($col = 'A'; $col != 'N'; $col++) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);
        }

        $objPHPExcel->createSheet(NULL, 2);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Pick List");  
        $letter='A';
        $lineCount=1;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','Itemcode');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1','Pick QUantity');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1','Pick Warehouse');

        $lineCount=2;

        $sqlGetItem="
        select  d.itemcode as itemcode, sum(d.quantity) as quantity, (select top 1 ib.dfltWH From OITW ia, OITM ib where ia.ItemCode=d.ItemCode and ia.ItemCode=ib.ItemCode)  as defaultWH
        from ordr a, rdr12 c, rdr1 d
        where (a.cardcode='c00001' or a.cardcode='c00002') and  a.docentry=c.docentry and a.docentry=d.docentry and a.docstatus='o' and a.printed='Y'
        group by d.ItemCode

        ";
        $resultGetItem=$db4->select($sqlGetItem);
        $rowsGetItems=$resultGetItem->fetchAll();
        foreach ($rowsGetItems as $rowsGetItem)
        {
            $itemcode=$rowsGetItem['itemcode'];
            $qty=$rowsGetItem['quantity'];
            $defaultWH=($rowsGetItem['defaultWH']=="" || $rowsGetItem['defaultWH'] === NULL ? "Check somewhere" : $rowsGetItem['defaultWH'] );
            $sqlGetWarehouseBest="select (b.onHand - b.IsCommited - $qty) as available from OITM a, OITW b where a.ItemCode=b.ItemCode and a.ItemCode='$itemcode' and b.WhsCode='$defaultWH'";
            $resultGetWarehouseBest=$db4->select($sqlGetWarehouseBest);
            $available=0;

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A$lineCount", $itemcode);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("B$lineCount", $qty);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("C$lineCount", $defaultWH);

            $lineCount++;
        }
            for ($col = 'A'; $col != 'D'; $col++) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);
        }

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $callStartTime = microtime(true);
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save($xlsxPath);

            if (file_exists($full_path)):?>
            Download Online Order CSV file:  <a href="download_online_order.php?filename=<?php echo $full_path?>"><?php echo $filename;?></a> <br/>
            <?php else:?>
            No file Found

            <?php endif;?>
                <?php if (file_exists($xlsxPath)):?>
            Download Online Order Excel File:  <a href="download_online_order.php?filename=<?php echo $xlsxPath?>"><?php echo $xlsx;?></a> <br/>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php
    }
    else{
        echo "No Sales Order Found";
    }
?>
```

I used `php -v` into Cent OS and I got:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/libr64/php/modules/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in line 0
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/libr64/php/modules/php_pdo.dll' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in line 0
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/libr64/php/modules/php_mysql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in line 0

PHP Warning: Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.0.18 (cli) (built: Apr 11 2017 14:25:57) (NTS)
```

I attempted the following (to no success -- already installed message):

```
yum install php-pdo
yum install php-pdo_mysql
```

Upon running `mysql -V` I got:

```
mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.36-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Anything constructive will be really helpful as this ongoing problem kept me puzzled for over several weeks. This code has no comments or documentations as the person who made this is no longer reachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to contact OpenCart Support to remote into my network and have them operate through our file system and Cent OS terminal. I had to share my screen through an instant messenger and have them obtain remote access under my supervision.

It looked like they knew the proper extension and proper follow-up commands to perform.

```
yum -y install mssql-server
cd /tmp/
mysql -u root -p website_com
mysql -u root -p website_com < oc.sql
mysql -u root -p website_com
shutdown -h +300
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your host mssql ext installed or not because you are trying to connect to mssql server using FileA.php

Sorry for my english

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just for clarification, in the event that mssql ext is not installed, what command can I enter to install this particular extension?
`yum  install ____` or a series of steps leading to this could help.

Comment: Your welcome. please check this link for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017 or search on google "install mssql extension for php on linux"

Comment: I ran through your microsoft link and followed the Red Hat 7 instructions to no avail. (Error said `bash: subscription-manager: command not found`)
If I googled your key terms, I would've already found the solution before posting it on here... But here I am still with the problem